# Slick 2: Delete row in slick with play framework

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, slick

This requirement should be really easy, but I don't know why is not working. I want to delete a row based on it's id using slick with play framework.

I'm following this example from [play-slick module](https://github.com/playframework/play-slick/blob/master/samples/computer-database/app/models/Models.scala), but compiler complains that value delete is not a member of scala.slick.lifted.Query[models.Tables.MyEntity,models.Tables.MyEntity#TableElementType].

My controller looks like:

```
def delete(id: Int) = DBAction{ implicit rs =>
  val q = MyEntity.where(_.id === id)
  q.delete
  Ok("Entity deleted")
}
```

I've imported the play.api.db.slick.Config.driver.simple._

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

My schema definition looks like:

```
class Cities(tag: Tag) extends Table[CityRow](tag, "cities") {
def * = (cod, name, state, lat, long, id) <> (CityRow.tupled, CityRow.unapply)
/** Maps whole row to an option. Useful for outer joins. */
def ? = (cod.?, name.?, state.?, lat, long, id.?).shaped.<>({r=>import r._; _1.map(_=>    CityRow.tupled((_1.get, _2.get, _3.get, _4, _5, _6.get)))}, (_:Any) =>  throw new Exception("Inserting into ? projection not supported."))

val cod: Column[String] = column[String]("cod")
val name: Column[String] = column[String]("name")
val state: Column[Int] = column[Int]("state")
val lat: Column[Option[String]] = column[Option[String]]("lat")
val long: Column[Option[String]] = column[Option[String]]("long")
val id: Column[Int] = column[Int]("id", O.AutoInc, O.PrimaryKey)

/** Foreign key referencing Departamentos (database name fk_ciudades_departamentos1) */
lazy val stateFk = foreignKey("fk_cities_states", state, States)(r => r.idstate, onUpdate=ForeignKeyAction.NoAction, onDelete=ForeignKeyAction.NoAction)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also had a look at that example some time ago and it looked wrong to me too, not sure wether I was doing something wrong myself or not, the delete function was always a bit tricky to get right, expecially using the `lifted.Query` (like you are doing). Later in the process I made it work importing the right drivers, in my case `scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple._`.

Edit after comment:

Probably you have an error in the shape function, hard to say without looking at your schema declaration. This is an example:

```
case class CityRow(id: Long, name: String) {

class City(tag: Tag) extends Table[CityRow](tag, "city") {

  def * = (id, name) <>(CityRow.tupled, CityRow.unapply)
    ^this is the shape function.

  def ? = (id.?, name).shaped.<>({
    r => import r._
      _1.map(_ => CityRow.tupled((_1.get, _2)))
  }, (_: Any) => throw new Exception("Inserting into ? projection not supported."))

  val id: Column[Long] = column[Long]("id", O.AutoInc, O.PrimaryKey)
  val name: Column[String] = column[String]("name")
}
```

Comment: Hi, @ende-neu thank you for answering. Importing the MySQL driver worked in my case with the delete complain, but if I try the conversion with Query I get this message from compiler: No matching Shape found. Slick does not know how to map the given types. Possible causes: T in Table[T] does not match your * projection. Or you use an unsupported type in a Query (e.g. scala List). Which solution should I use or what is the prefered way?

Comment: I'm sorry I made a mistake, I trusted Intellij too much apparently. Using `Query` or not doesn'T change much, the delete method would still be non available and I don't know why, as I said I usually import the right drivers and the delete becomes available in scope.

Comment: ok it seems more reasonable importing the drivers, but I don't see any apparent difference with my schema definition, in fact I let the code generator define it in this particular example, I've added it to the original question. Thanks anyway.

Comment: nowxue. The probably is probably that you used a different import for the schema definition, probably the one generated by the code generator, and for the play controller. You need to import from the the exact same object, otherwise Scala doesn't recognize them as the same due to path dependent typing and cannot apply the conversion needed.

Comment: @cvogt If I may, this should be made explicit in the Slick documentation in my opinion, it was very hard to get right the first time. If I remember correctly I got there looking at all possible examples and scanning the differences one by one until by chance I saw the packages import statements (and until now I didn't even really understood why), also you can see yourself that the question keeps coming up on SO.